# How can I split code-blocks into a list?

Tags: python, css, regex, list, python-3.x

I want to split the contents of a CSS file into code blocks and push each block of code into a list using Python 3.5.

So, given this CSS:

```
h1 {color: #333, background-color: transparent}
h2 {
  font-weight:300
}
h3
{
  font-weight: 200
}
```

We can clearly tell that it has multiple styles and / or types of indentation meaning the CSS has to be tidied to get this:

```
h1 {
  color: #333,background-color: transparent;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: 300;
}

h3 {
  font-weight: 200;
}
```

How can I use Python to read a tidied string of CSS and push every block of code inside it into a Python list like this:

```
styles = [
  "h1 {\n  color: #333,background-color: transparent;\n}",
  "h2 {\n  font-weight: 300;\n}",
  "h3 {\n  font-weight: 200;\n}"
]
```

I would also like to point out that RegExp is not really my forte and I'm not quite sure what RegEx to use, but I was thinking that I could use RegExp & `[].split(...);` together to achieve this.

Possibly even use RegExp to eliminate the need to tidy the stylesheet before splitting the code-blocks in it.

NOTE: I've checked this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11592347) question out but unfortunately that didn't help either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the pythonic way to implement a css parser/replacer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11592347/what-is-the-pythonic-way-to-implement-a-css-parser-replacer)

Comment: @pvg No, unfortunately that did not solve my problem.

Comment: @Mango No need to implement a parser yourself, you can use a small library. I've outlined it in my answer below.

Comment: @Mango it actually does, the way you want to solve your problem is akin to this infamous SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5087125
Don't do it, use a parser, there are small efficient ones that do this simply and properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This implementation is done using `tinycss`, a simple pure python [css parser](http://pythonhosted.org/tinycss/index.html).

This works on **untidied** css. As long as it is legal.

```
import tinycss
from collections import defaultdict

parser = tinycss.make_parser('page3')
# use parse_stylesheet_files to read from a file.
stylesheet = parser.parse_stylesheet("""h1 {color: #333; background-color: transparent}
        h2 {
              font-weight:300
        }
        h3
        {
              font-weight: 200
        }
        h1{
        padding: 0px;}
        """)

# Initialize to empty list if key does not exists
# This allows to group multiple blocks with same selectors
temp = defaultdict(list)

for rule in stylesheet.rules:
    for dec in rule.declarations:
       temp[rule.selector.as_css()].append((dec.name, dec.value.as_css()))

print(temp)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>,
            {'h1': [('color', '#333'),
                    ('background-color', 'transparent'),
                    ('padding', '0px')],
             'h2': [('font-weight', '300')],
             'h3': [('font-weight', '200')]})
```

See how different `h1` blocks got clubbed into a single list. I'm not extremely aware of the intricacies of CSS, but it's easy to prevent this from happening.

This is *much more flexible* in that it covers **ALL** edge cases, works with selectors, CSS2, and CSS3, unlike a solution with regular expressions.

*Please note: I've pushed everything into a dictionary, but you can easily push it as a list as-well. Let me know if you want something with pure lists, but it should be relatively trivial if you understand what I'm doing.*

Comment: What cases will a regex not cover? Assuming that the CSS is always formatted correctly, it should always work https://repl.it/C5ws/7

Comment: @JacobGray assuming that it's correctly formatted. And if isn't, you anyways need a parser, so might as well have a way to solve it without needing to tidy the css.

Comment: The OP is asking how to split a *formatted* piece of CSS, so I think it is safe to assume that the input is always formatted. Even if the input isn't always formatted, you can still split it regardless of formatting by `re.compile("(})").split(css)`. I just don't see any point in using a library to parse the entire stylesheet when all you want to do is split each rule

Comment: What if there is a SINGLE extra 'whitespace' present, your solution breaks apart completely, that too silently. Comments, brackets inside comments, complete blocks inside comments, tab characters, there are always edge cases and It's definitely a bad idea to use RegEx for something like this.

Comment: This could be made shorter and clearer with a defaultdict making the comment and if unnecessary. Also, is the b prefix on the string really needed?

Comment: I actually used a `defaultdict` in my local copy, but I chose to avoid it to  explain clearly what I'm trying to do. I'll add it in the solution eitherways. Yes `tinycss` only works on byte like object.

Comment: `tinycss` works just fine on unicode strings, just call `parse_stylesheet` instead of the function you're using. It's python 3 so you know you have a unicode literal and none of this extra stuff is needed.

Comment: @pvg How could I have been so stupid lol. I missed the documentation right in front of my eyes! Sorry. Fixed the answer.

Comment: @MiteshNinja thank you for the answer, it works brilliantly.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with a simple file read and replace:

```
styles = []
with open('file.css') as file:
    style = []
    for line in file.readlines():
        # If line is empty
        if not line.strip():
            # If a block is non-empty
            if style:
                styles.append("".join(style))
                style = []
        else:
            # Add to the current block
            style.append(line)
    styles.append("".join(style))
```

Output:

```
>>> for s in styles: s
h1 {\n  color: #333,background-color: transparent;\n}\n
h2 {\n  font-weight: 300;\n}\n
h3 {\n  font-weight: 200;\n}\n
```

Comment: This code will horribly break even if there's a single extra blank line literally ANYWHERE in the entire css style sheet.

Comment: @MiteshNinja By "horribly break", I assume you meant there will be empty lines in `styles` (if you meant something else, please clarify). Thanks for pointing that out. Fixed it.

Comment: I don't think you understand. Your code will now 'horribly' break if there's a single extra blank line present ANYWHERE except if the newline is between 2 blocks. If there's an extra line present inside a block, it will assume that the block is finished and push it onto `styles`. Please re-check your code.