# BeautifulSoup findall get text but return empty

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am scraping a website and would like to find specific content based on style, so I do

```
soup.find_all('style')
```

[image]

and it does return some result/text, but once I use .text `soup_name.find_all('style')[0].text` to extract the text, it returns an empty string

[image]

What can I do to extract the text in the style tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `.contents[0]`:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_doc = """\
<style>
    th { border: none; }
</style>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html5lib")

print(soup.find("style").contents[0])
```

Prints:

```
    th { border: none; }
```

Comment: I use `soup.find_all('style')[0].contents`, and it works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else, you can just use

```py
str(soup.find('style')).strip()[7:-8].strip()
```

to get the stylesheet as one string. If you want to know more about parsing the css, you might like to [check this out.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11685846/12652373)